# I am not able to install Mlivus standalone through Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, milvus

my-release-etcd-0                               1/1     Running   0          3m58s

my-release-milvus-standalone-8587d4796d-r579n   0/1     Running   0          3m58s

my-release-minio-54fc79dbdf-gzlsh               1/1     Running   0          3m58s

[2022/01/21 07:30:00.210 +00:00] [DEBUG] [client.go:82] ["DataCoordClient, not existed in msess "] [key=datacoord] ["len of msess"=0]
[2022/01/21 07:30:00.209 +00:00] [ERROR] [client.go:115] ["failed to get client address"] [error="number of datacoord is incorrect, 0"] [stack="github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient.(*ClientBase).connect\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient/client.go:115\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient.(*ClientBase).GetGrpcClient\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient/client.go:87\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient.(*ClientBase).callOnce\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient/client.go:177\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient.(*ClientBase).ReCall\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/grpcclient/client.go:217\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/datacoord/client.(*Client).GetComponentStates\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/datacoord/client/client.go:110\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil.WaitForComponentStates.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil/func.go:50\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/retry.Do\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/retry/retry.go:34\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil.WaitForComponentStates\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil/func.go:74\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil.WaitForComponentHealthy\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/util/funcutil/func.go:89\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/querycoord.(*Server).init\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/querycoord/service.go:183\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/querycoord.(*Server).Run\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/distributed/querycoord/service.go:95\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/cmd/components.(*QueryCoord).Run\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/cmd/components/query_coord.go:50\ngithub.com/milvus-io/milvus/cmd/roles.(*MilvusRoles).runQueryCoord.func1\n\t/go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/cmd/roles/roles.go:178"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you deploy with docker-compose or Minikube? https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0/install_standalone-docker.md

Also, there is a slack channel (https://slack.milvus.io/) for the Milvus community, where a lot of active community members solve Milvus-related problems together. Please join if you need further troubleshooting. Cheers!

Comment: I did it with minikube, I had installed previous rc8 or rc9 the same way but it is not working for pre-ga.

Comment: Basically I installed using these steps
https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0/install_standalone-helm.md
And not it is not working for pre-GA

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and when I did a kubernetes describe pod on milvus-minio-0, I noticed the following error:

```
Events:
Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
----     ------            ----                ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  55s (x12 over 14m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory.
```

I think you haven't allocated enough memory to your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try.